# Using Mod_Rewrite to edit a cookie conditionally

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

1. My cookie value JSESSIONID is of the form id.bunchofstuff
2. My cookie value name_of_msfcookie is of the form bunchofstuff2
3. If the MSF cookie exists, i want to change my JSESSIONID to id.bunchofstuff2.

But how? Here is my attempt:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} name_of_msfcookie=(.*) #checks for  existence of value (value can be any character or series of characters) in cookie
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [CO=JSESSIONID:JSESSIONID[7].name_of_msfcookie:.place.com]
```

It doesn't work - I think JSESSIONID[7].name_of_msfcookie is invalid syntax )-=. I can't think of any valid syntax to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax works fine for me and the cookie that gets set looks correct. This is what I see when I send a request to apache with those rules with a `name_of_msfcookie=something` cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=JSESSIONID[7].name_of_msfcookie; path=/; domain=.place.com
Vary: Cookie
```

Not sure if that's what you are trying to do though. Note that the [CO] flag *sends the cookie to the browser*.